# What causing errors with this stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to process monthly jobs. The stored procedure will loop through all the available jobs and do some calculation before it's inserted into a table. It was fine for most jobs but for some jobs, there will be an error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Below is the section where it says the error occurred:

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT *
              FROM aastocks  aastk
              WHERE aastk.estno = @lcEstno
            and 0 in (aastk.cartonratio1, 
                      aastk.cartonratio2, 
                      aastk.cartonratio3, 
                      aastk.cartonratio4, 
                      aastk.cartonratio5)
        )  EXECUTE ru_est_stocksum @lcEstNo
```

@lcEstNo was defined in the previous code.

```
SET @lcEstno = (SELECT MAX(estno) FROM dbo.v_est_joblist WHERE ljob = @tcLjob)
```

MAX() should return only 1 value and I don't understand why the multi value error.

Well, as it turns out, the line number of the error is not the same as the line number in the Stored Procedure. So the problem actually resides in the following code(After I comment out the below section and there is no error). But I am not able to find out which subquery is returning more than 1 value. Any idea ?

```
INSERT INTO @JCDTotals
    SELECT  @tcLjob, coalesce(cast( ap.deptno as char(4)),'????') as deptno,
        CASE WHEN  coalesce(v_depuse_qty.DepUse, 1) = 1 THEN
                            CASE WHEN @tcCostBase = 'D' THEN CASE WHEN ap.procgroup = 'I' THEN aaprocqt.dmcstmat1 + aaprocqt.dmcstmat2 + aaprocqt.dmcstmat3 END
                                 WHEN @tcCostBase = 'A' THEN CASE WHEN ap.procgroup = 'I' THEN aaprocqt.costmats1 + aaprocqt.costmats2 + aaprocqt.costmats3 END
                                 ELSE ' 0 '
                             END
             ELSE 0     END AS ecostmats,
        CASE WHEN  coalesce(v_depuse_qty.DepUse, 1) = 1 THEN CASE WHEN @tcCostBase = 'D' THEN (1 / (1 + (ap.burden/100))) ELSE  1  END
                 * aaprocqt.costlab
             ELSE 0
             END        AS ecostlab,
        CASE WHEN coalesce(v_depuse_qty.DepUse, 1) = 1 THEN aaprocqt.proctime
             ELSE 0
             END        AS eprochours,
        0.0 AS bcostmats,
        0.0 AS bcostlab,
        0 AS bprochours,
        0.0 AS acostmats,
        0.0 AS acostlab,
        0 AS aprochours,
        0.0 AS chgcost,
        0 AS dirlab,
        0.0 AS aacost,
        0.0 AS pecost,
        0.0 AS otcost,
        0 AS sell
    FROM (
        SELECT  aaproces.idnumber,
            aaproces.estno,
            aaproces.procgroup,
            aaproces.partno,
                    aaproces.[lineno],
                    aaproces.counter,
            ssproces.burden,
            case WHEN aaproces.procgroup = 'I' then ssinvent.deptno
                     else ssproces.deptno end                   as deptno,
                case WHEN aaproces.procgroup = 'I' then ssinvent.matno
                     else STR(ssproces.procno,6) end                as procno,
            case WHEN aaproces.procgroup = 'I' then ssinvent.material
                     else ssproces.process end                  as process  
          FROM dbo.aaproces
            LEFT JOIN dbo.SSINVENT ON ssinvent.matno = aaproces.matno
                AND ssinvent.invtype IN ('G', 'I', 'F', 'S')
            LEFT JOIN dbo.SSPROCES ON ssproces.procno = aaproces.procno
          WHERE ((aaproces.procgroup = 'I' and ssinvent.deptno is not null)
            OR (aaproces.procgroup <> 'I' and ssproces.deptno is not null))
            AND ((aaproces.procgroup = 'I' and ssinvent.matno is not null)
            OR (aaproces.procgroup <> 'I' and ssproces.procno is not null))
        ) ap
        INNER join dbo.v_est_joblist
            on v_est_joblist.estno = ap.estno
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.aaprocqt
            on aaprocqt.estno = ap.estno
            and ap.[lineno] = aaprocqt.[lineno]and aaprocqt.procgroup = ap.procgroup
            and ap.partno = aaprocqt.partno and ap.counter = aaprocqt.counter and aaprocqt.qty = v_est_joblist.alt
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_depuse_qty
            ON v_est_joblist.estno = v_depuse_qty.estno
                AND v_depuse_qty.deptno = ap.deptno
                AND V_DEPUSE_QTY.LJOB = V_EST_JOBLIST.LJOB
                AND V_DEPUSE_QTY.ALT = V_EST_JOBLIST.ALT
    WHERE  v_est_joblist.ljob = @tcLjob
    --  AND  ssdept.divno like @lcDivNo
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------- PROCESS MATERIAL1,MATERIAL2,MATERIAL3 (ESTIMATED)
    UNION ALL
      SELECT @tcLjob, coalesce(ssinvent.deptno,'????') as deptno,
        CASE WHEN  coalesce((SELECT v_depuse_qty.DepUse FROM dbo.v_depuse_qty WHERE v_est_joblist.estno = v_depuse_qty.estno
                    AND ssinvent.deptno = v_depuse_qty.deptno
                    AND V_DEPUSE_QTY.LJOB = V_EST_JOBLIST.LJOB
                    AND V_DEPUSE_QTY.ALT = V_EST_JOBLIST.ALT), 1) = 1 THEN CASE     WHEN sq.CopyNum = 1 THEN CASE WHEN @tcCostBase = 'D' THEN aaprocqt.dmcstmat1 ELSE aaprocqt.costmats1 END
                                                    WHEN sq.CopyNum = 2 THEN CASE WHEN @tcCostBase = 'D' THEN aaprocqt.dmcstmat2 ELSE aaprocqt.costmats2 END
                                                    WHEN sq.CopyNum = 3 THEN CASE WHEN @tcCostBase = 'D' THEN aaprocqt.dmcstmat3 ELSE aaprocqt.costmats3 END
                                                    END
             ELSE 0
             END    AS ecostmats,
            0 AS ecostlab,
        0 AS eprochours,
        0 AS bcostmats,
        0 AS bcostlab,
        0 AS bprochours,
        0.0 AS acostmats,
        0.0 AS acostlab,
        0 AS aprochours,
        0.0 AS chgcost,
        0 AS dirlab,
        0.0 AS aacost,
        0.0 AS pecost,
        0.0 AS otcost,
        0 AS sell
      FROM dbo.aaproces JOIN dbo.v_est_joblist on v_est_joblist.estno = aaproces.estno
        CROSS JOIN @NumCopies sq
        LEFT JOIN dbo.ssproces on aaproces.procno = ssproces.procno
        LEFT JOIN dbo.ssinvent on ssinvent.matno = ( case   when sq.CopyNum = 1 then CASE WHEN aaproces.manmatno = ''  THEN ssproces.matno1 ELSE aaproces.manmatno  END
                                    when sq.CopyNum = 2 then CASE WHEN aaproces.manmatno2 = '' THEN ssproces.matno2 ELSE aaproces.manmatno2 END
                                    when sq.CopyNum = 3 then CASE WHEN aaproces.manmatno3 = '' THEN ssproces.matno3 ELSE aaproces.manmatno3 END
                                    end)
        JOIN dbo.aaprocqt on aaprocqt.estno = aaproces.estno and aaprocqt.procgroup = aaproces.procgroup
            and aaproces.partno = aaprocqt.partno and aaproces.[lineno] = aaprocqt.[lineno]
            and aaproces.counter = aaprocqt.counter and aaprocqt.qty = v_est_joblist.alt
      WHERE  aaproces.procgroup <> 'I'
         --and sq.CopyNum < 4
         and case   when sq.CopyNum = 1 then (manmatno  + matno1 )
            when sq.CopyNum = 2 then (aaproces.manmatno2 + ssproces.matno2 )
            when sq.CopyNum = 3 then (manmatno3 + matno3 )
            end <> ''
         AND v_est_joblist.ljob = @tcLjob
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------- STOCKS (ESTIMATED)
    UNION ALL
      SELECT @tcLjob, coalesce(case when aastocks.houvend = 'H' then ssinvent.deptno
                else case when aapthead.parttype = 'S' then @opt_stockccs
                          else @opt_stockccr end end,'????')
        as deptno,
        CASE WHEN  coalesce((SELECT v_depuse_qty.DepUse FROM dbo.v_depuse_qty WHERE v_est_joblist.estno = v_depuse_qty.estno
                    AND v_depuse_qty.deptno = ssdept.deptno
                    AND V_DEPUSE_QTY.LJOB = V_EST_JOBLIST.LJOB
                    AND V_DEPUSE_QTY.ALT = V_EST_JOBLIST.ALT), 1) = 1 THEN CASE WHEN @tcCostBase = 'D' THEN
                            CASE WHEN aastocks.houvend = 'V' THEN (1 / (1 + (ssdept.burden/100)))
                                   ELSE (1 / (1 + (ssinvent.burden/100))) END
                                ELSE  1  END  *
            case when v_est_joblist.alt = 1 then aastocks.stkcost1 * aastocks.cartonratio1
                     when v_est_joblist.alt = 2 then aastocks.stkcost2 * aastocks.cartonratio2
                     when v_est_joblist.alt = 3 then aastocks.stkcost3 * aastocks.cartonratio3
                     when v_est_joblist.alt = 4 then aastocks.stkcost4 * aastocks.cartonratio4
                     when v_est_joblist.alt = 5 then aastocks.stkcost5 * aastocks.cartonratio5
                 END
             ELSE 0
             END                AS ecostmats,
        0 as ecostlab,
        0 as eprochours,
        0 AS bcostmats,
        0 AS bcostlab,
        0 AS bprochours,
        0.0 AS acostmats,
        0.0 AS acostlab,
        0 AS aprochours,
        0.0 AS chgcost,
        0 AS dirlab,
        0.0 AS aacost,
        0.0 AS pecost,
        0.0 AS otcost,
        0 AS sell
    FROM dbo.aapthead
        INNER JOIN dbo.aastocks on aapthead.estno = aastocks.estno and aapthead.partno = aastocks.partno
        INNER JOIN dbo.v_est_joblist on v_est_joblist.estno = aapthead.estno
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ssinvent on aastocks.matno = ssinvent.matno
                AND ssinvent.invtype IN ('R', 'S')
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ssdept ON ssdept.deptno = (CASE WHEN aastocks.houvend = 'H' THEN ssinvent.deptno
                                     ELSE CASE WHEN aapthead.parttype = 'S' THEN @opt_stockccs
                                               ELSE  @opt_stockccr
                                   END
                             END)
    WHERE  v_est_joblist.ljob = @tcLjob
      AND  1 = [dbo].[DivisionCheck] (ssdept.divno,@tcDivNo)
```

Comment: I don't see `MAX()` anywhere.

Comment: The code you have in your question is ok, it will not cause the error. Could it be caused by `ru_est_stocksum`? If not, please include your whole code.

Comment: @roryap It's in the line which assign value to the variable lcEstno. Sorry if I didn't make it more clear.

Comment: @JamesZ SQL server indicates that the error happens at line "WHERE aastk.estno = @lcEstno". So that's why I am puzzling why that's the case. Also, I would have look into the ru_est_stocksum if it's not encrypted.

Comment: Well you can try commenting out code until you find out what's actually causing it

Answer (score 0):

In the three code samples shown, I see nothing that would generate that subquery error message.

- `exists()` subqueries are designed to handle multilple returned rows
- The `select max()` subquery is properly formed
- There is nothing that would cause problems if the only subquery in the third block returned multiple rows

Ergo, it must be something else. My guess—and this is a guess—is that, in the third bock, tables `v_est_joblist` and/or `v_depuse_qty` are in fact views (I use something like the `v_Blah` convention myself), and something’s going wrong in one of them. If so, you’d need to test these views, see what they’re returning when joined into the main query as they are.

Comment: I include some more codes where I think the problem resides. The stored procedure work fine for 95% of the @tcLjob value. I am going to double check the views too. Thanks.

Comment: The more code you add, the harder your problem gets. Best advice I've got is to break it down into smaller and smaller pieces (each select within the union, each view and each subquery within a select, etc.) and test them individually.

Answer (score -2):

It appears that your "in" expression is being supplied with more than one row of values. So, although "exists" can accept multiple rows as input, "0 in (aastk.cartonratio1, ...) cannot.